# Append code using javascript in selenium webdriver script

Tags: java, javascript, testing, selenium

I'm trying to execute javascript to append some code in a selenium webdriver script.But I get the following error:

> )?missing synthax

The following is my javascript

```
String item1= $("<div id=Unique1 class='dojoItem Name' style=padding:.5em;`display:inline-block;width:16em;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;>filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>").appendTo('#select');
```

This is my webdriver code:

```
openServiceFlows();
            driver.findElement(By.id("test")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("open")).sendKeys("allow_ALL_DATA111");
            driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys("102");
            executeJavascript("item1");
```

The following is used to execute my javascript

```
protected void executeJavascript(String script){

    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    je.executeScript(script);       
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the line    $("<div id=Unique1 class='dojoItem Name' style=padding:.5em;display:inline-block;width:16em;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;>filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>").appendTo('#select');

Comment: produces this error missing ) after argument list

Comment: I am still not clear how you are passing arguments to `executeJavaScript`? and, is it `Selenium webdriver` ?

Comment: protected void executeJavascript(String script){

  JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  try {
   Thread.sleep(1500);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  je.executeScript(script);       
 }

Comment: In javascript this code will throw an error: `String item1 = ...` and in java there is no `$()` sintax... so, how are you declaring the `item1` variable? post all your code

Comment: it is declared as follows  String item1 =  "$(<div id=Unique1 class='dojoItem Name' style=padding:.5em;`display:inline-block;width:16em;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;>filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>").appendTo('#select');";

Comment: I will edit the question once I am allowed